# Is there a way for the code on a site to detect whether or not someone accessed it through a QR code?

Tags: qr-code

I want to make a site that uses QR codes, and for user analytics I want to see how many people access it through the code, but I don't want a GET parameter for this because I don't want any URL guessing giving me incorrect stuff.  Any way to detect QR code access?

Answer (score 2):

**No**.

Besides something in the URL, you only really have the headers. For example, if you assume all mobile traffic to the URL is from a QR code reader, you could sniff for a mobile User-Agent header. Doesn't seem very robust, tho.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, but you can use a URL shortener such as bit.ly to collect analytics.